# Where does "pop it in the oven" come from?

Tags: etymology, phrases, expressions

Where and when did the phrase "pop it in the oven" originate?

Comment: I always thought my dad made that one up...

Comment: @Dodgie If you’re talking about your dad referring thereby to your having a new sibling on the way, I’m pretty sure others have used it that way.

Answer (score 6):

For 'pop', [Oxford Dictionaries has](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pop):

> **Verb:**
>   [with object and adverbial of direction] put or move (something) somewhere quickly
>
> *She popped a pen into her pocket*

In that sense, you could say that the phrase "pop it in the oven" is just a straight use of the verb rather than being idiomatic. (Though that doesn't explain how the word took on that meaning, or when this usage became popular)

---

The earliest usage Google Books have recorded [is from 1869](http://books.google.com/books?id=Kt4iAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA134&dq=%22pop%20it%20in%20the%20oven%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Mi-aUqihPMPC0QXy7oCgDA&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA), from a book called Soimême:

> I generally have one going, and **I pop it in the oven** the first thing and eat it hot, and I really want next to no breakfast.

That would make it  nearly 150 years old at least.

[On Google NGram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pop%20it%20in%20the%20oven&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,pop%20it%20in%20the%20oven;,c0#t1;,pop%20it%20in%20the%20oven;,c1), it seems to come on in popularity in the 40s–70s and then rocketed in usage in the 80s — I'd wonder if this might have a corelation with the rise of cookbooks and TV shows by home cooks like Martha Stewart in the States and Delia Smith in the UK who were meant to be presenting cooking in a simple "no nonsense" approach (**Disclaimer:** complete conjucture!)

[image: ngram viewer]

Comment: And let us not any of us forget [the immortal ***Poppin’*** Fresh, better known as the Pillsbury Doughboy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pillsbury_Doughboy), who is now 51 years old.

Comment: Aha! Do you think his middle name is "the oven"! :D

Comment: No, amaizingly [sic] enough, I was thinking of [an even cornier middle name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiffy_Pop).

Comment: Can we please stop referring to Oxford Dictionaries as the OED? This is the OED:http://www.oed.com/

Comment: @BarrieEngland Of course, you're right! — will correct.

Comment: @tchrist They do look amaizing!! I want one! :)

Comment: I think "pop" used in that sense is uniquely British. I don't think Americans "pop in and see the neighbours", or "pop another invitation in the post" etc. The matter was of significance in 1997, when a British nanny was standing trial in the US, accused of first degree murder of a baby in her care. Forensic evidence revealed cranial fractures, which the prosecution contended had been caused by the nanny. The defence case was that they were pre-existent to her care of the child. (continued)

Comment: (Brought forward) At one point in response to cross examination she said "When the phone rang I just popped him on the bed", which in British parlance would mean that she just placed him on the bed while she answered the phone. However this usage was quite foreign to the US jury, whose understanding of "popped" meant that she punched the child.